# cannot build/package console app to resource group project as webjob

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2022

I have a core 6.0 console app with webjob host code and packages.

I'm trying to add the project to a `Resource Group Project` `.deployproj`

I can add web apps as referenced projects and those build and get zipped into the bin output of the deployproj project.

I cannot get the console webjob app to build/deploy

I keep getting the following error:
`error MSB4057: The target "Package" does not exist in the project.`

I've tried adding Azure publish to the console app but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is not possible to build and deploy console applications to Resource Group project as a webjob.
As mentioned in the [official MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/create-visual-studio-deployment-project#create-azure-resource-group-project), it is possible to deploy the webhost and website related projects.

[image]

I tried to add/build my console app to Resource group project, I was facing the same issue:

[image]

And also, I have tried to add/build web application with Resource group project and succeeded.

[image]

I suspect it is because the template that has been selected as `web app` when creating Azure resource group project.

[image]